# QMediaPlayer / задержка перед воспроизведением

Tags: c++, qt

Занялся написанием небольшой игрушки и вот добравшись до музыкально-звуковой составляющий столкнулся с проблемой.

```
    QMediaPlayer *bulletSound = new QMediaPlayer();
    bulletSound->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/rsc/sounds/bullet.mp3"));

    if (bulletSound->state() == QMediaPlayer::PlayingState) {
        bulletSound->setPosition(0);
    } else if (bulletSound->state() == QMediaPlayer::StoppedState) {
        bulletSound->play();
    }
```

Этот звуковой файл должен воспроизводиться всякий раз, когда игрок делает выстрел. И он воспроизводится, но когда снаряд пролетит уже приличное расстояние. Имеет место быть какая-то задержка. Как свести ее к минимуму?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делается через предзагрузку. Ваши файлы просто читаете в буферы, которые где-то размещаете в памяти, при вызове метода стрельбы соответственно вызываете

```
QBuffer tmp(&bullet_sound_array);
mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(), &tmp);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

В этом примере надо следить, чтобы tmp буфер существовал до конца воспроизведения, поэтому лучше сразу после чтения перегонять QByteArray в QBuffer

Также можно попробовать разместить аудио файлы в .qrc файле, но это раздует .ехе до неимоверных размеров.

Comment: Почему-то не сработало. В конструкторе записал файл в буфер, вызываю play() в методе обработки keyPressEvent и получаю звук с задержкой около секунды.

Comment: @foxtermore, QMediaPlayer::LowLatency флаг пробовали?